# Prepopulating a Form with only specific items from a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to building an app that will register students for classes.  I have a student model, a subject model and a registration model.  My registration form is broken down by three hours (First Hour, Second Hour, Third Hour).  What I would like to do is pre-populate my registration form with with the classes that are for each hour.

For instance we only offer math & science first hour and english & PE second hour.  So when a student registers the first hour options should only be Math or Science and second hour options should only be English or PE.

Answer (score 0):

Just select values for your dropdown lists from DB and use these values in [select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) helper (look at first example).

Answer (score 0):

You can query data using ajax request and on success of ajax, parse returned data as you require and append to select field using select2.js . You can use different ajax request for each hour and query only required fields for each request.